# Access a specific child element, using classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is part of a wider project, I have just broken the code down to its basics.

What I'm trying to do specifically, is when you click the button, it should:

1. Identify the element clicked (target)
2. Get its parent element
3. Identify the UL element inside the parent
4. Alert the class name of the UL element

Everything works, but I can't figure out how to identify the UL element of the parent.

```js
function getClassOfUl(e) {
   
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  var parent = target.parentNode;
  
  alert(theparent.***UL***.className);

}

$('.class2').on('click', function(e){
 getClassOfUl(e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
   <div class="class2">Click Me</div>
   <ul class="class3"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery you can do it like this:

```js
function getClassOfUl() {
  alert($(this).parent().children('ul').attr('class'));
}

$('.class2').on('click', getClassOfUl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
   <div class="class2">Click Me</div>
   <ul class="class3"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `parent.querySelector('ul')` to get the first `ul` child of the parent element.

```js
function getClassOfUl(e) {
   
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  var parent = target.parentNode;
  
  alert(parent.querySelector('ul').className);

}

$('.class2').on('click', function(e){
 getClassOfUl(e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
   <div class="class2">Click Me</div>
   <ul class="class3"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: or to answer the actual question, i.e. "using classes", `parent.querySelector('.class3')`

Comment: @JaromandaX I think they want to alert an unknown class name for a ul element.

Comment: @JaromandaX No that's not right. They want the class name of the `ul` element.

Comment: you're probably right, the question title is badly worded **Access a specific child element, using classes** suggests using classes to access an element, not alert the class of an element by node name

Comment: Yes, I want to identify what will be an unknown class. Sorry, the title infers the elements should be identified by classes, and not IDs.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but as I'm using jQuery I'll take one of the other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, the appropriate way to do that would be something like:

```
function getClassOfUl(e) {

  var target = $(this); // or $(e.currentTarget);
  var parent = target.parent();

  alert(parent.children('ul').attr('class'));

}

$('.class2').on('click', getClassOfUl);
```

Comment: I think you mean `parent` rather than `theparent`. Although that will alert undefined.

Comment: It's because the anonymous function is changing what the context of `this` is.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/g9rcmbze/

Here's a jsFiddle. Hopefully this helps you out.

```
function getClassOfUl(e) {

  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  var parent = target.parentElement;
  var ul = parent.lastElementChild;
  var className = ul.className;

  alert(className);

}
```

Comment: The last element will not always be the `ul` element.

Comment: Doesn't say that explicitly. Though I see how it would be more flexible using another method.

Comment: It does state *"Identify the UL element inside the parent"*.